# Sysprep is removing all updates

Tags: windows, windows-update, sysprep, winpe

When we use Sysprep, it removes all Windows updates. When we do this, we have to install all the same updates every time we use the image. Is there a way we can make Sysprep keep the updates? Here is the command we use to sysprep a computer:

```
sysprep /oobe /generalize /unattend:unattend.xml
```

Thanks for any suggestions anyone has! Doing Google searches, I cannot seem to find any details on the matter. I would even be willing to accept answers that I can avoid Sysprep but still remove unique identifiers.

Comment: Is it actually removing the updates (abnormal), or just clearing the update history (normal)?

Comment: Since i have to reinstall the same updates over and over i would say its removing the actual updates. It is also reverting to the non updated verion of IE 9 after sysprep and imagex.

Comment: Is it _all_ updates, or just specific ones?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 ALL updates. I was just giving IE as an example.

Comment: The thing is, Sysprep doesn't do this. :)  Are you sure the master image has all these updates on it?  Were they fully finalized (all reboots done, no updates waiting) before you used Sysprep?  Do you have any exclusions setup in your Unattand.xml?

Comment: I am sure they was completed. We have been doing this process for 6 months and every time it's the same. 130ish updates even tho i ran the updates before creating the image. I will post my unattend file for you to look over.

Comment: If you haven't updated your master in 6 months, then that's probably why the images computers required updates..?  By Exclusions in your Unattend.xml, I meant SPECIFCIALLY ADDED file exclusions, not "Stuff you may have missed". ;)

Comment: No... We have recreated the image many and many of times in the last 6 months. I have installed and completed all ypdates, sysprepped, captured using imagex and used it a few hours later and had 130ish updates to the freshly used image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some testing and changing our process one step at a time, I have found out that imagex removes the updates. I changed the process to sysprepping and then use clonezilla and that fixed the issue.